# Iterating a result array with Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate a result array with Ansible.

I'm launching a few *AWS EC2* instances like this:

```
- name: ec2-static-instances
  ec2:
    <all atributes here...>
  with_itens:
    - instance1
    - instance2
  register: instances
```

Ok, then I get the result of the instances above in a array of hashs/dictionaries. I'm able to get each instance id like this:

```
{{ instances.results[0].instance_ids[0] }}
{{ instances.results[1].instance_ids[0] }}
```

But, I would like to make it more dynamic and not need to know in advance how many elements I have in the array. I tried something like that, but it doesn't work.

```
# Elastic IPs for instances created above
- name: eip_static_instances
  ec2_eip:
    region: us-east-1
    in_vpc: yes
    instance_id: "{{ item.instance_id[0] }}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ instances.results }}"
```

I get the following error:

**fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'dict object' has no attribute 'instance_id'"}**

I went through the official documentation, but none of the examples shown there seem to do what I want to. Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

It turns out my problem was a simples mistake with the variable name, as anyone can see above (*item.instance_id* instead of *item.instance_id**s***, the later being the right one). As reference for readers, fix it and the code above will work. Thanks.

Comment: The output you showed has the property named as `instance_ids` with an `s` on the end, but the task that's referencing it is only using `item.instance_id` without the `s`.  Make sure you have your variable names correct.

Comment: Oh, obviously! How could I not see this? I'm sorry for that. I think I had been working for too long on this thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting my comment as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered:

The output you showed has the property named as instance_ids with an s on the end, but the task that's referencing it is only using item.instance_id without the s. Make sure you have your variable names correct.